# Outlook 2011 crashing on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have a user who isn't able to open Outlook 2011 on his iMac. As soon as he opens Outlook 2011 it crashes. All other Microsoft Office applications work fine.

He has a iMac 27-inch, Mid 2011 running OS X Lion 10.7.2.

[This is the crash report](http://pastebin.com/Q6kByC60) that is created, if it's any help.

This same Mac was running OS X 10.6 and also had Outlook issues, but since upgrading to Lion it hasn't resolved any issues.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The same happened to me. This is how I fixed it: go to `/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Office/` and launch Microsoft Database Utility.app and rebuild the Main Identity.

Comment: **This helped!**

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a framework error. This means that at least one of the Office components has not been updated correctly and isn't working well with other parts. Try updating Outlook with the newest service pack. If that doesn't work you might need to try reinstalling Outlook.

There could be a permission problem as well when trying to load Framework libraries. You can try looking at the files in the Identities folder and make sure they are not locked. the location to them is:

Hard Drive>User>**User Name here**>Documents>Microsoft User Data>Office 2011 Identities

Here is a resource one framework errors:

http://www.office.mvps.org/error/framework.html

Comment: Thanks, I ended up re-installing Office 2011 that resolved the issue with Outlook crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a few computers in my network with this problem, the problem is in the server.
Open Outlook, go offline and hold for few minutes, quit Outlook. Open again, hold a minute and go online. Should hold till next restart.